# Datepicker problemas de actual

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

Las fechas de un formulario que se despliegan cuando nos posicionamos en el campo son siempre del 2023 de calendario (actual). Esto me resulta incómodo porque estamos haciendo para el año 2022, y nunca podrán ser adquiridos con posterioridad a esa fecha. mi pregunta es como se hace para que aparezca el calendario 2022?
te paso el código de react:

```
export const Datepicker = (props) => {

  return (
    <DatePicker

      style={{ width: '100%' }}

      className="form-control"

      locale="es"

      peekNextMonth

      showYearDropdown

      showMonthDropdown

      disabledKeyboardNavigation

      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
      {...props }

    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Para <DatePicker> estas utilizando alguna librería UI ?

Comment: si, la ultima version

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad maxDate del datepicker para asignar hasta que fecha pueda seleccionar el usuario:

```
   // maxDate = 04/28/2023 (hay que recordar que el valor 0 = enero, 1 = febrero).
   // Por ende el valor 3 = abril
    const maxDate = new Date(2023, 3, 28);
    <DatePicker
      style={{ width: '100%' }}
      className="form-control"
      locale="es"
      peekNextMonth
      showYearDropdown
      showMonthDropdown
      disabledKeyboardNavigation
      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
      maxDate={maxDate}
      {...props }
    />
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!